# Why are attachments no longer downloading?

Tags: download, attachments, yahoo-mail

I use yahoo.com to retrieve my email (I have an att.net account).

Lately I have not been able to download attachments. I click Save > Save to my Computer, and they are not (saved to my computer).

I had no trouble in the past, so why the sudden change? This happens both at home *and* at work, so it's not the machine, it's the account, or ... ???

When I click the Save link, it "flashes" but that's it. Just to be sure the file didn't "silently/invisibly" download, I search the entire hard drive, and nada/nichts/nothing.

Does anybody know what could be causing/what could rectify this?

### UPDATE

Following mtashev's suggestion, I used F12 to see what was happening when trying to download a file. It seems as if yahoo/att.net is having a dickens of a time with it:

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
[blocked] The page at 'https://ad.doubleclick.net/adi/N6375.1041586.YAHOOINCGENOMEFROM/B7978853.2;…/tid/97f33d7d-bb61-4e37-b565-ad1d4c16f92b/click.ic?;ord=635247821973146808?' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://cdn.doubleverify.com/dvtp_src.js?ctx=798288&cmp=7978853&sid=1397956&…v=doubleclick&crt=56752245&crtname=&chnl=&unit=&pid=&uid=&dvtagver=6.1.src': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 ad.doubleclick.net/adi/N6375.1041586.YAHOOINCGENOMEFROM/B7978853.2;sz=300x2…d/97f33d7d-bb61-4e37-b565-ad1d4c16f92b/click.ic?;ord=635247821973146808?:1
[blocked] The page at 'https://ad.doubleclick.net/adi/N6375.1041586.YAHOOINCGENOMEFROM/B7978853.2;…/tid/97f33d7d-bb61-4e37-b565-ad1d4c16f92b/click.ic?;ord=635247821973146808?' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://c.betrad.com/surly.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 ad.doubleclick.net/adi/N6375.1041586.YAHOOINCGENOMEFROM/B7978853.2;sz=300x2…d/97f33d7d-bb61-4e37-b565-ad1d4c16f92b/click.ic?;ord=635247821973146808?:1
[blocked] The page at 'https://ad.doubleclick.net/adi/N6375.1041586.YAHOOINCGENOMEFROM/B7978853.2;…/tid/97f33d7d-bb61-4e37-b565-ad1d4c16f92b/click.ic?;ord=635247821973146808?' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://core.insightexpressai.com/adServer/adServerESI.aspx?bannerID=252758&…N6375.1041586.YAHOOINCGENOMEFROM&creativeID=56752245&placementID=105716900': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 ad.doubleclick.net/adi/N6375.1041586.YAHOOINCGENOMEFROM/B7978853.2;sz=300x2…d/97f33d7d-bb61-4e37-b565-ad1d4c16f92b/click.ic?;ord=635247821973146808?:1
[blocked] The page at 'https://ad.doubleclick.net/adi/N7140.1220341.GENOME.COM/B7607970.7;sz=728x9…/tid/4ffafd70-cd2b-4e24-b437-4620412ac3fa/click.ic?;ord=635247824790855389?' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://choices.truste.com/ca?pid=icrossing01&aid=westelm_icrossing01&cid=7607970_1341276&js=st_0': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 ad.doubleclick.net/adi/N7140.1220341.GENOME.COM/B7607970.7;sz=728x90;click=…d/4ffafd70-cd2b-4e24-b437-4620412ac3fa/click.ic?;ord=635247824790855389?:1
Blocked a frame with origin "http://a1.interclick.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://ads.yahoo.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
Blocked a frame with origin "http://a1.interclick.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL secure-us.imrworldwide.com/cgi-bin/m?ci=ade2013-ca&at=view&rt=banner&st=image&ca=mars_pet_006&cr=digitas_mars&pc=8494314&ce=display&rnd=232965756:1
10
Blocked a frame with origin "http://a1.interclick.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://ads.yahoo.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL secure-us.imrworldwide.com/cgi-bin/m?ci=ade2013-ca&at=view&rt=banner&st=image&ca=mars_pet_006&cr=digitas_mars&pc=8494314&ce=display&rnd=77626968:1
11
Blocked a frame with origin "http://a1.interclick.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://ads.yahoo.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL secure-us.imrworldwide.com/cgi-bin/m?ci=ade2013-ca&at=view&rt=banner&st=image&ca=mars_pet_006&cr=digitas_mars&pc=8494314&ce=display&rnd=130175888:1
13
Blocked a frame with origin "http://a1.interclick.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://ads.yahoo.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
2
Blocked a frame with origin "http://a1.interclick.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://ads.yahoo.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. vce_st.js:1
[blocked] The page at 'https://ad.doubleclick.net/adi/N7140.1220341.GENOME.COM/B7607970.7;sz=728x9…/tid/f075d3fd-f2af-4d50-840c-a11982956d77/click.ic?;ord=635247850965121047?' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://choices.truste.com/ca?pid=icrossing01&aid=westelm_icrossing01&cid=7607970_1341276&js=st_0': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 VM696 click.ic?;ord=635247850965121047?:1
Blocked a frame with origin "http://a1.interclick.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://ads.yahoo.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. vce_st.js:1
Blocked a frame with origin "http://a1.interclick.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://ads.yahoo.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. ca?aid=interclick03&pid=interclick01&cid=aid3833cid60441&w=300&h=250&plc=tr&c=interclick03cont16044…:4
Blocked a frame with origin "http://a1.interclick.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame. ca?aid=interclick03&pid=interclick01&cid=aid3833cid60441&w=300&h=250&plc=tr&c=interclick03cont16044…:147
[blocked] The page at 'https://ad.doubleclick.net/adi/N7140.1220341.GENOME.COM/B7607970.7;sz=728x9…/tid/fe0f81b4-c7e9-4a4e-abda-59dfc859cc14/click.ic?;ord=635247851055936428?' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://choices.truste.com/ca?pid=icrossing01&aid=westelm_icrossing01&cid=7607970_1341276&js=st_0': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 VM1374 click.ic?;ord=635247851055936428?:1
Blocked a frame with origin "http://a1.interclick.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://ads.yahoo.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. ca?aid=interclick03&pid=interclick01&cid=aid3833cid60441&w=300&h=250&plc=tr&c=interclick03cont16044…:4
Blocked a frame with origin "http://a1.interclick.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame. ca?aid=interclick03&pid=interclick01&cid=aid3833cid60441&w=300&h=250&plc=tr&c=interclick03cont16044…:147
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://a1.interclick.com/getInPageJSProcess.aspx?a=51&b=53468&cid=634860023…w3y6usf0o-PVDK2lc.p-7Yp3MeqS8Z-EMTY-%2c&isif=t&rurld=ads.yahoo.com&sl=true". getInPage.aspx?a=51&b=53468&cid=634860023424735165&click=http%3A%2F%2Fads%2Eyahoo%2Ecom%2Fclk%3F3%2…:152
[blocked] The page at 'https://ad.doubleclick.net/adi/N7140.1220341.GENOME.COM/B7607970.7;sz=728x9…/tid/d211833f-b130-41e2-b482-108b74742e28/click.ic?;ord=635247851193035586?' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://choices.truste.com/ca?pid=icrossing01&aid=westelm_icrossing01&cid=7607970_1341276&js=st_0': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 click.ic?;ord=635247851193035586?:1
Blocked a frame with origin "http://a1.interclick.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://ads.yahoo.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. ca?aid=interclick03&pid=interclick01&cid=aid3833cid60441&w=300&h=250&plc=tr&c=interclick03cont16044…:4
Blocked a frame with origin "http://a1.interclick.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame. ca?aid=interclick03&pid=interclick01&cid=aid3833cid60441&w=300&h=250&plc=tr&c=interclick03cont16044…:147
```

Comment: I've asked the moderators on Web Apps and they said the question should rather stay here, as it could very well be a browser issue. I personally would also recommend keeping it on Super User.

Comment: Even without the log, I would have said that some security software is blocking one or more servers that Yahoo! is trying to use. Your log confirms that. Do you have AdBlock or some other blocking extension installed? If so, have you tried disabling it (and reloading the page) to see if it works?

Comment: @Synetech: The only extensions enabled are Google Docs, HTML Tidy Browser Extension, Web Developer Checklist, and YSlow

Comment: Well YSlow is related to Yahoo! and while its description doesn’t seem to indicate that it should affect anything, you may as well see what happens if you disable it. Also, what about other security software like an anti-virus, firewall, ad-blocker, `HOSTS` file, etc.? The log seems to indicate that some things are being blocked, but it doesn’t look like they should affect attachments. It seems to be a problem with the page including elements from the non-HTTPS (ad)servers. If it *used* to work, maybe they changed something that is not causing an XSS issue. I’ll test to see if it’s just you…

Comment: I just sent myself a message with an attachment and was able to download it without problem. I had similar events in the JavaScript console, but that didn’t prevent the download. [This is](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YDMmK.png) what I see and what I used to download it. Is that what is failing for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can try out:

First disable all plug-ins/widgets on your browser and try to download a simple file from your mail like .jpg or .txt. Check your network tab in developer tools (press F12) for errors.

Next, try different browser (By the way you can mention which one you are using). I've noticed a bit of a strange behavior with Chrome, weirdly. Although downloads do work with me.

If this doesn't help, try with a sample account (you can create a dummy one if you don't have other available > send a file there and try to save it to your pc). If with the new account you have success then send an email to yahoo support team and tell them to run a check with your account and explain the weird behavior.

Also, you might want to disable your AntiVirus (if you have one) so that it doesn't interfere with Norton antivirus check that Yahoo performs before every download.

Comment: I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Interesting; I tried to download an image my brother sent me, mashed the "Save to Computer" link, nothing happened (as has been the problem lately), so I mashed F12 and got a slew of errors in the Console tab. I'm adding them to an Update here.

Comment: Ok, what happens when you try IE or Firefox? Have you tried with Chrome extensions disabled? Did you try with other yahoo account?

Answer (score 1):

Some workarounds you may try ([source](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/2dX1kCr6AZQ)) :

- Log out of yahoo email, delete bookmark, either re-enter yahoo.com/Mail or use mail.yahoo.com, then log back in.
  After you are logged in, bookmark the page as your (new) Yahoo Mail page.
- Some people had more success with `http://att.yahoo.com/`
- Clear the history & cache & cookies
- Try going into yahoo mail settings, Security tab, then select `Always use HTTPS`
- If you have installed any Internet security suite or anti-virus, try disabling it
- Check if this is happening in another browser than Chrome
- To [disable all extensions](http://googlesystem.blogspot.fr/2010/02/google-chrome-safe-mode.html) in Chrome, see if this happens in an
  incognito window.
  If it does not happen, then some extension is causing this.

Another [remark](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?locale=en_US&page=content&id=SLN3222) is that
Yahoo Mail does not accept attachments that have been encrypted, or coded to prevent unauthorized access. Meaning that they only accept attachments that their anti-virus
knows how to scan.

Comment: This did it: "Some people had more success with http://att.yahoo.com/" I will award the bounty ASAP (c. 19 hours from now).

Answer (score 1):

If you're having problems downloading attachments through your email-ids (any email service like gmail, yahoo etc.) and are unable to download them, you can always hang on to some Download manager like DAP or IDM (though there are many more but I use IDM only) you can download those attachments through them. Though downloading attachments can sometimes be troublesome because of some malware/adware/anti-virus/could be a virus also/one of your plug-ins/or also could be some extensions that might be giving problems.

What you can do to download them is that you can restart your browser, try another browser also you can change your account (can create a new one or existing id and send the attachments to other id). Also disable your anti-virus and any firewall and adblocker. Also as I mentioned above you can download the attachments through Download Manager (IDM and others).

What you need to do is : -

**First open your email id i.e. your email account (yahoo, gmail etc.)**

[image]

**Then copy the URL link from your browser and add it to IDM Options -> Sites Logins (remember the link should refer to your email-id should work either way)**

**Then add your email-id (username for websites which use username instead of email-ids) and password in it and save.**

[image]
[image]

**(you can open the IDM options menu from here)**

[image]

**Then go to your email-id and to your attachment and Right click on it and select to download link through IDM (when you install IDM it will integrate it's extensions in installed browsers)**

[image]

**A confirmation box will appear asking to rename the file as provided by the sender (original name as though when you will download a file the file name is present some numbers i.e. file-ids that will change to it's normal filename when the server accepts your username and password).**

[image]

That's it. You downloaded the attachments through IDM successfully from email accounts :D